# Hey guys I tried to solve this problem using R code but didn't get the result. I am unable to find the issue with the code as well

Tags: r, math

```
s <- sample(1:9, replace = FALSE)
for (i in 1:1000000) {
  if ((10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3] + (10*s[6] + s[7]) == (10*s[8] + s[9])) {
    c <- (10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3]
    f <- c %% 10
    if (f != s[1] & f != s[2] & (c - f)/10 != s[1] & (c - f)/10 != s[2]) {
      print(s)
    }
  }else{
      s <- sample(1:9, replace = FALSE)
    }

}
```

Here is the link to the problem I was trying to solve.

[image]

Here is the correct answer to the problem which my R loop is unable to solve.

[image]

If I set s as the correct answer I got it right which means there isn't a problem with the if statement.

```
    s <- c(1,7,4,6,8,2,5,9,3)
if ((10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3] + (10*s[6] + s[7]) == (10*s[8] + s[9])) {
  c <- (10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3]
  f <- c %% 10
  if (f != s[1] & f != s[2] & (c - f)/10 != s[1] & (c - f)/10 != s[2]) {
    print(s)
  }
  }else{
    s <- sample(1:9)
}
```

Here is the output with the correct answer.

[image]

Comment: On each iteration of the for-loop, I think your intent is to get a fresh sample for `s`. But currently, your code is only getting a fresh sample on rare occasions -- when it passes the first conditional, and fails the second one. (You could print out `s` on a few iterations to see that it's being retained on most iterations).

Comment: Hey I incorporated the changes you said but still I am unable to get the answer. Is there s problem with the code?

Answer (score 0):

The blocking issue you're having is that the sample isn't being refreshed on each iteration through the for-loop. It's only being refreshed if the first if statement is executed, and the second else statement executed -- which is pretty rare.

Here's the revised code, getting a fresh sample on each iteration.

```
for (i in 1:1000000) {
  # Get a fresh sample on each iteration
  s <- sample(1:9, replace = FALSE)

  if ((10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3] + (10*s[6] + s[7]) == (10*s[8] + s[9])) {
    c <- (10*s[1] + s[2])*s[3]
    f <- c %% 10
    if (f != s[1] & f != s[2] & (c - f)/10 != s[1] & (c - f)/10 != s[2]) {
      print(s)
    }
  }
}
```